# How can I get the value from this multiple array object with VueJs

Tags: vue.js

Hi I have multidimensional array that it has a value but I do not know how to get it, my array is this:

```
  0: [{total_collection: 537600, date: "2022-03-01"}, {total_collection: 260700, date: "2022-03-02"},…]
  1: [{total_collection: 349300, date: "2022-03-01"}, {total_collection: 321300, date: "2022-03-02"},…]
```

If I store that data into a variable called this.total_values then I do this

```
 {{ total_values[0][1] }}
```

and it displays:

```
 {total_collection: 537600, date: "2022-03-01"}
```

If you see I could do this:

```
 {{  total_values[0][1].total_collection }}
```

And it should return 537600 but it does not work it returns:

```
Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'total_collection')"
```

Why? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you fetch that data structure via ajax call? Maybe its not yet present when vue renders the initial state of the ui.

Comment: @Andreas No. He clearly get the data from `total_values[0][1]`

Comment: And where does that, as you called it, array come from? ^^ As you mentioned, the problem is "elsewhere"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get your data from API or do you send data to this component using `props`?
if you use these things you will get undefined it's because the array doesn't have a value when you want to get value. you have to wait to data be assigned to the array. you can use this to fix the problem. test with this code:

```
<template v-if="total_values && total_values.length > 0">
    {{  total_values[0][1].total_collection }} 
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The posted code works: [see this playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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). Your problem is elsewhere.

```html
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
const array = ref([
  [{total_collection: 537600, date: "2022-03-01"}, {total_collection: 260700, date: "2022-03-02"}],
  [{total_collection: 349300, date: "2022-03-01"}, {total_collection: 321300, date: "2022-03-02"}]
])
</script>
<template>
  {{array[0][1].total_collection}}
</template>
```